# Angular Reactive Forms default value of input for updating data is 'undefined' when submitting although binding to value property not placeholder

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular7

I have made a reusable component in Angular that I'm using to build multiple forms for the purpose of priving a quick way to modify multiple data-items.

I have 2 input fields in this component that I'm binding via input properties when iterating on an array with *ngFor. All is well and works well with ids and showing the data but the problem that I'm having is when I'm pushing to update the value of those 2 fields show up as 'undefined' (unless I modify them).

My Markup is:

```
<input 
      #catTitle
      matInput 
      placeholder="Document Title" 
      [value]="categoryTitle"
      formControlName="categoryTitle"
      [errorStateMatcher]="matcher"
      >
```

My backend is:

```
  categoryForm = new FormGroup({
    categoryTitle: new FormControl('', [Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(50)]),
    categoryDescription: new FormControl('', [Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(200)])
  })
```

I'm sure I'm missing out on something really stupid on this one.

Comment: can you create a demo (stackblitz) base on your code? , I think you need to update categoryTitle from control instand of      `[value]="categoryTitle"`

Comment: @malbarmawi Yes! I ended up just putting that variable inside the form control and then creating the form group onInit to make sure the value is not 'null' as that variable will be an input property that needs to be plugged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VI realized shortly that in my code I set the default value of the Form Control to blank here: `categoryTitle: new FormControl(''`  and have since modified to take a variable there and made sure it's not set as 'null' by creating the form after view init.